# index 2 is out of bounds

Tags: python, index-error, emcee

I have the following code which is about constraining the parameters.
I get this error when I run the code:

`samples[:, 2] = np.exp(samples[:, 2])
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2`

Any Help Please, How should I do to fix this error? I appreciate your help and your attention
 import numpy as np
    import emcee
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from math import *
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.integrate import quad
    from scipy.integrate import odeint

```
xx=np.array([0.01,0.012,0.014,0.016])    #or xx=[0.01.......]
yy=np.array([32.95388698,33.87900347,33.84214074,34.11856704])
Cov=[[137,168],[28155,-2217]]     
#Initial points
rc=0.09, c=0.7, H01 = 70, O_m1 = 0.31, z0=0, M=1, O_m = 0.31, H0=70
np.random.seed(123)

def ant(z,O_m,O_D):          # first function   
    return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2)*(1+O_m*z)-z*(2+z)*O_D)

def new_calculation(n):        
    O_D=1-O_m
    q=quad(ant,0,xx[n],args=(O_m,O_D))[0]     #using the first function in integration
    h=log10((1+xx[n])*q)   
   fn=(yy[n]-M-h)
   return fn

def log_likelihood(theta):    
    M, O_m= theta
    f_list = []
    for i in range(2):  # the value '2' reflects matrix size
                f_list.append(new_calculation(i))
    rdag=[f_list]
    rmat=[[f] for f in f_list]
    mm=np.dot(rdag,Cov)
    zz=np.dot(mm,rmat)
    hh=np.linalg.det(zz)*0.000001
    return hh          #calculation of matrix


   from scipy.optimize import minimize
np.random.seed(42)
nll = lambda *args: -log_likelihood(*args)
initial = np.array([M, O_m1]) + 0.1*np.random.randn(2)
soln = minimize(nll, initial)
M_ml, O_m0_ml = soln.x

def log_prior(theta):
    M, O_m= theta
    if  0.22 < O_m < 0.32 and 0 < M < 12:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf

def log_probability(theta):
    lp = log_prior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + log_likelihood(theta)

pos = soln.x + 1e-4*np.random.randn(80, 2)
nwalkers, ndim = pos.shape
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_probability)
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, 250);
samples = sampler.chain[:, 50:, :].reshape((-1, ndim))
from IPython.display import display, Math
samples[:, 2] = np.exp(samples[:, 2])         #the error may be resulted from here
m_mcmc, b_mcmc, f_mcmc = map(lambda v: (v[1], v[2]-v[1], v[1]-v[0]),
                         zip(*np.percentile(samples, [16, 50, 84],
                                            axis=0)))
print(m_mcmc, b_mcmc)
```

Comment: could you give the ouput for `print(samples)` just before the error, please?

Comment: @Tekay37  it is `[[  0.95064125   0.30706864]
 [  0.95064125   0.30706864]
 [  1.0504276    0.31836635]
 ..., 
 [  9.67483904   0.29647078]
 [ 10.04456516   0.29916585]
 [  7.73066364   0.29886876]]`
this is the printing of samples

Comment: So `len(samples) == 1` and `len(samples[0]) > 6` ? That might be your problem

Comment: @Tekay37  and do you have any idea to solve it plz?

Comment: I actually can't reproduce your error on a pyfiddle. So replacing `2` with `0` or `1` is my best guess to solve the error. But I can't say that will give you the right results.

Answer (score 1):

You got 2 parameter `O_m` and `M` which you set a range for them. but you got `[:,2]` here. 2 is for 3 parameters! we start from 0 not 1. this is Numpy.
then you want to define 3 out put for your code! `m_mcmc, b_mcmc, f_mcmc`
this must be 2 outputs not three. I am not sure what are m and b and f. but I know one one them must be removed.
Then you got the answer.

Comment: Ow, I forgot to remove f_mcmc and thank you for numpy advice starting from 0.